# What code should I surround with run(){}?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I finished a 2000-line Swing + SQL program and I'd like to add to it a login window before everything is initialized. The login window is a `JFrame` class, instanced from the main program.

So my main app needs to implement `Runnable`. All I want with the thread I'm creating out of it is waiting -with `wait()`- until the login thread finishes -and uses `notify()`-.

My program consist of dozens of visual components, methods, `main()`, constructor, initializer, etc. What's the minimum amount of code I should surround with `run(){}`?

This is an example of what I want to do. It's not by any means correct (I suppose) but you'll get it:

```
private void initialize() { // Called from main()

    this.setBounds(100, 200, 1024, 576);
    this.setTitle("Main app");
    this.setVisible(false);

    Runnable runnable = new Visual_Login();
    Thread login_thread = new Thread(runnable);

    login_thread.run();     
    main_thread.wait();

    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setContentPane(getJContentPane());

}
```

(...I hope I'm understanding concurrency well)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Something is very odd in your question. The design doesn't sound correct. The login dialog should probably be a modal JDialog and not a JFrame. Do also note that you just can't create a new thread and invoke swing-methods. Swing is single threaded, and swing methods should be invoked from the AWT thread.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. Just curious, what's the AWT thread? Can there be two AWT threads?

Comment: No, there is a single AWT-Event thread, usually called the _event dispatch thread_ (EDT); see also [Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need another thread here.

At the end of login action, if the login is successful create an instance of your main jframe class and dispose the login jframe

```
class MainFrame extend  JFrame{
 ...
}

class LoginFrame extends JFrame{
.
.
.
 public void login(){
   boolean loginSuccess = checkCredentials(username,password);
   if(loginSuccess){
      MainFrame main = new MainFrame();
      .
      .
      this.dispose();

   }else{
    //show some error to user
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Very clever, I was thinking the opposite way. Thank you.

Comment: You can choose the most suitable answer for your case by clicking the tick next to it.

Comment: Although your idea is the one I'm implementing, all answers are being useful to me so I'm not picking one. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I get what you want to achieve but ... if you want run `initialize` in background then you need:

```
 Runnable doInit = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        component.initialize()
     }
 };
```

To run it you can optionally do:

```
// if you are running a swing UI and you want the dispatcher to handle the thread.
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doInit);
```

or

```
//if you want to start the thread yourself.
Thread t = new Thread(doInit);
t.start()
```

... can't really go further than this because the rest really depends on your logic.

And just to finish, it is not worth to use a thread here unless your `initialize` method does something that takes considerable amount of time freezing the rest of the app. It doesn't seem that `initialize` is doing anything but to set some SWING properties.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't make myself clear enough. Initialize actually does much work (via its last sentence) so it can't run as a background task.

Answer (score 1):

You [start a thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) with the `start()` method and not the `run()` method. The Thread class will call the run method when it has properly configured itself.

In your case it should be:

```
Runnable runnable = new Visual_Login();
Thread login_thread = new Thread(runnable);
login_thread.start();
// run() will be called later.

wait();
// waits for another thread to do notify or notifyAll.
// it should be around here where the runnable thread will "run()"
```

Other than that if you're planning to block the application anyway then why do you need to start another thread?

Comment: ... because of particularities of my program. Thanks for the start() correction.